# mysql GROUP_REPLICATION Description The old member rejoined the group abnormally

Tags: mysql

```
2023-08-09T16:39:41.931968Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error connecting to all peers. Member join failed. Local port: 33061'
2023-08-09T16:39:42.594398Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member was unable to join the group. Local port: 33061'
2023-08-09T16:39:47.819059Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error connecting to all peers. Member join failed. Local port: 33061'
2023-08-09T16:39:47.884893Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member was unable to join the group. Local port: 33061'
```

This is my third node. After the stop GROUP_REPLICATION command was used to actively exit the group, the above error message was reported when the node re-joined the group. Everything was normal before the exit, and the port and configuration remained unchanged.

Hope someone can fix this

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you ever fix it somehow?